# set a github branch to pull(read) only

Tags: github

Is it possible to set a particular branch in a shared/public repository to read-only?
(I don't want to make the whole repository read-only)

For instance, `master` should be read-only to most people except the project manager or the person who does the coordinating tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, access right are repository-wide.

Which means, if you need that kind of restriction, you would need a *private* fork of that repo, with only the PM as a collaborator: he/she will be able to pull what he/she need.

Then the PM can `push --force` back to the master branch of the public repo (which should clearly advertised that master can be changed at any time, and should never been pushed to directly by devs)

Or you can leave the first repo alone, and make the second repo public (with a warning to only *pull* from that second repo managed by the PM, never push).
The devs can add a second remote reference to their local repo, the first being for them to push or pull, the second being to pull main release versions as stored by the PM in that second repo.

---

Beside that, the only other solution is an intermediate repo on a server you control, on top of which you can add an [authorization layer](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/auth.html) like [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) (that would allows read-only branches), and which can proceed pushing to GitHub if the commits are deemed "valid".